# Unusual "Size" value displayed in Finder; meaning of arrows in Size column

Tags: macos, icloud, finder, icon

While investigating an issue of iCloud failing to sync on my iMac I noticed a couple of unusual things in Finder.  In the "Size" column some values were preceded by an upward-pointing or downward-pointing arrow.  One of the folder items had an arrow and a particularly odd "Size" value consisting of the text "760... 1 byte".  The ellipsis did not expand into more text when I expanded the Size column to its maximum width, as indicated here:

[image]

I have not been able to locate a description of what the arrows displayed in the "Size" column are intended to signify.  I'm guessing they could be iCloud-related data transfers. Does anyone know what they indicate?

And does anyone know what that Size information for the "ESP32" folder is indicating?

Incidentally, taking the above image with the Grab utility - which is set to use iCloud storage - immediately "fixed" my iCloud sync issue which is what I had originally intended to write a question about.  I almost feel like adding a Community question to suggest that as a possible solution to fixing a "stuck" iCloud sync issue.

Answer (score 1):

The up arrow means the file is uploading. The reason for the unusual size is because that's the size that has been uploaded. Not the size of the total file. Once the file finishes uploading to your computer it will have a "normal" looking size and the arrow will disappear.

Downloading 4 files/folders at once will slow them all down. So just be patient.